# Bandpass Amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, filter, active-filter, frequency-response

[image]

[image: Bandapss filter]

This is my frequency response , the point is if i change the capacitor values C1 and C4 my signal distorts on the second lobe in time domain and gain curve is not flat in the range. MY bandwidth is in the range of 100khz to 500kHZ, It is not a strict condition important is it works at 300khz.

I am designing a bandpass amplifier and stuck understanding the magnitude and phase response of my signal.
My input is 300kHz sine wave and output should be amplified signal with some phase shift but i am not understanding my circuit and its magnitude and phase response. I took some part of the design from previous revisions but fail to see what effect it has on my circuit. Can someone please explain in detail the frequency response of my circuit in detail? So i am sure i am not missing anything which is in detail.

The important thing is the output should be a bandpass filter to work in the range of 300kHz.

Comment: @All - Although well-intentioned, the long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore comments so far have been moved to chat & should be continued there (see the comment below). || As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here might be deleted without notice. *Keep it in chat now, please!* || All relevant improvements to the question decided during the chat, should be made via a question [edit], not as a comment. When someone has got enough information to post an answer, please answer it as usual. Thanks

Comment: *Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149646/discussion-on-question-by-electronics4learning-bandpass-amplifier); please do not continue the discussion here.*

Comment: @SamG Thanks for the kind note. I understand and accept the rational behind the decision. I'd like to be allowed to leave this breadcrumb here to check back in a week. But today I've decided i won't keep a separate list on paper nor will I separately keep track through another managed process adding still more work to me needed to effectively use chat. The site tools hide things and I'm not creating an end-run around it, either.

Comment: @periblepsis - Summary: One of the purposes of not having comments on a Q/A after they've been moved to chat, is to avoid splitting / duplicating information and discussion across both places. Your comment above doesn't do that, so I have no immediate plan to delete it. || However all comments should be considered [temporary](/help/privileges/comment) so I make no promises about its future.